# Authentication error while fetching yahoo contacts using contacts gem in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using contacts gem in my rails 3 application. In case of yahoo contacts it is acting weirdly . It is working fine on local machine but on staging server it is giving authentication error . Below is the log for local and staging server for test account :

### on local server :

Started POST "/invitations/new_invitations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-04 15:31:46 +0530
  Processing by InvitationsController#new_invitations as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TanjgyK36VgohyE/woBmBGYq2DGbPLmts3j+IIG/c1Q=", "provider"=>"yahoo", "email"=>"testvin27@yahoo.in", "pass"=>"123456", "commit"=>"Import your address book"}

User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 316) LIMIT 1

Rendered invitations/new_invitations.js.erb (1.2ms)

Completed 200 OK in 9594ms (Views: 30.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

### on staging server :

Started POST "/invitations/new_invitations" for 14.99.166.38 at 2011-08-04 10:07:34 +0000
  Processing by InvitationsController#new_invitations as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ibMbauQlR1yN2bOBZotirAtZa28dMpzL/m9jc5XBP8M=", "provider"=>"yahoo", "email"=>"testvin27@yahoo.in", "pass"=>"123456", "commit"=>"Import your address book"}

User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 130) LIMIT 1

**Contacts::AuthenticationError: Username and password do not match>**

Rendered invitations/new_invitations.js.erb (0.4ms)

Any about this kind of behaviour ??